# How to remove anything to the left and included the first instance of a special character in a string 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the SQL statement to do the following? Kinda stuck here *scratch head

- 139G - Hello World (Happy Files)
- 140G - Mike Tyson (US -Files)

to become

- Hello World (Happy Files)
- Mike Tyson (US -Files)

Answer (score 2):

```
select substring(Value, charindex(' - ', Value) + 2, len(Value))
from MyTable
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9b4a/9)

Comment: Just a note to the OP - this approach (which is the same one I would have opted for, given the data) assumes that (space)(dash)(space) always appears between the data that you don't want, and the data that you do. Additionally, if the "G" is always present, you could use charindex('G - ', Value)

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(Value, charindex(' - ', Value) + 2, (len(Value) - charindex(' - ', Value) + 1) ) from MyTable
```